# Doing simple addition in Razor View page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor-pages

I have a problem with my razor view code not doing simple addition using random number generation. See below razor view code.

```
Random rand = new Random();
int r1 = rand.Next(0,100);
int r2 = rand.Next(0,100);
int ans = r1 + r2;

string incorrect = "";
string correct = "";
string response = "";
int input = 0;

if(IsPost){
    response = Request.Form["response"];
    input = Convert.ToInt32(response);
    if(input != ans){
        incorrect = "Incorrect";
    }
    else if(input == ans){
        correct = "Correct";
    }
}
```

In the view, I'm using an `<input>` to accept the users answer to the equation. See view code below.

```
<div class="danger">@incorrect</div>
<div class="success">@correct</div>
<form method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group inline-div">
            <label for="response" class="control-control col-sm-2 text-20 text-right">@r1 + @r2 = </label>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <input type="text" name="response" class="form-control" placeholder="@ans" required />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default form-control" value="Submit" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
<div>The correct answer is: @ans</div>
```

The problem is, no matter what I, as the user, enters (correct or incorrect) razor is saying it's incorrect. Can anyone help me identify what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First block of code is being executed twice - first time during page rendering (asking question), second time when answer was submitted. Value of variable `ans` is calculated as random and it's different in first and second case.

For example:
- rendering, '2 + 2 = ?', `ans` is 4
- '4' is submitted, but `ans` is 6 this time, so 'incorrect' is displayed

You need to include values `r1` and `r2` into form data and use them is POST handler for calculate correct answer:

Razor:

```
<input type="hidden" name="r1" value="@r1" />
<input type="hidden" name="r2" value="@r2" />
```

Handler:

```
if(IsPost){
   ans = int.Parse(Request.Form["r1"]) + int.Parse(Request.Form["r2"]);
   ...
   if (ans != input) {
      ...
   }
}
```